# Tried both import gdal and from osgeo import gdal but not helping although gdal is installed. Is there a way to change environments to make it work?

Tags: python, spyder, gdal

I want to use gdal to read raster files. This is a mess for me now because I literally reinstalled everything and went over almost all the posts trying all the installation methods and environment changes. Please help, I am a somewhat new to Python, recently switched from MATLAB.

I see I have multiple installations and environments:

```
base                  *  /Users/name/anaconda3
                         /opt/anaconda3
```

And I know I need to work in /opt/anaconda3 to do my stuff on Spyder. I need gdal and it is there, I an see it with conda list.

Is there a way to change the base environment? I wanted to keep it simple like one environment one python, Anaconda-Spyder uses the same too but ruined it for my self.

Macbook Processor: 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7

**In Spyder**
-Python 3.11.5 (main, Sep 11 2023, 08:19:27) [Clang 14.0.6 ]
-IPython 8.15.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

**In Terminal**
-conda 23.7.4
-zsh: command not found: python

It just started working after I toggled between Python interpreters. I did *import gdal* and it did not give me any error, I know I should have stopped there. At the same time I was frantically going over all the posts and I made a mistake of writing *sys.path* in my code and it started giving me the same error again: *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'*

I tried all interpreters, activating all the environments restarting and changing interpreters in Spyder and so on.

In Spyder I typed   *print(os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV'])*   it gives 'base' as an answer and I think it should be /opt/anaconda3. When I type *print(os.environ["CONDA_PREFIX"])*, it gives '/Users/name/anaconda3' as the output.

Comment: I solved the working issue by creating a new environment in terminal and then installing gdal there again and selecting the same environment in Spyder and then using from osgeo import gdal (this time import gdal didn't work). I did this after updating everything. 

But I would love to hear solutions to keep everything simple without needing to create many environments.

Comment: Using different environments is the way to keep everything simple. If you install everything you ever need in one environment, that environment will become very complex because of all dependencies between packages, and you will soon run into trouble. So, different, simple environments are a blessing, not something to avoid.

Comment: Yes looks like it, still learning. Thank you!